# How to make multiple async calls in a Blazor Server Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm creating my first Blazor App and trying to implement account registration functionality. If the user enters a valid email and password for registration, I want to register them, sign them in under their new account, and then route them to the "/fetchdata" page.

UserService.cs

```
        public class RegisterResponse
        {
            public bool Succeeded;
            public string Message;
        }
        public async Task<RegisterResponse> Register(string email, string password)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return new RegisterResponse { Succeeded = true, Message = $"{email}'s account created!" };
            }
            else
            {
                return new RegisterResponse { Succeeded = false, Message = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault().Description };
            }
        }
```

Index.razor

```
    private async Task Register()
    {
        var res = await UserService.Register(registerModel.Email, registerModel.Password);
        if (res.Succeeded)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage = res.Message;
        }
    }
```

The user is registered, however each await used in the service goes back to the client and the application breaks (most often due to and error 'Headers are readonly...', which stems from trying to edit headers after the response has been initated).

But the only response I want going back to Index.razor is the RegisterResponse object.

Do I have something set up wrong here? Should I be using a Controller instead of a Service?

Comment: What exact error are you getting, and what is the stack trace that includes the nearest line of your own class?

Comment: Exception: "Headers are read-only, response has already started".

Stack Trace:
at Project.UserService.Register (this line: `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);`)
at Project.Pages.Index.Register

Every await seems to make a response to the client. After we register (but before checking if result.Succeded) it send me to the client when I'm on a breakpoint before continuing.

Comment: So the second await also tries to make a response, but the response has already been made so it can't.